# Memberpress. How to get user subscription time

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to check the time a user have been with an ongoing subscription on Memberpress.

I already found the way to know if a user is active with

```
user_can( $user_id, 'memberpress_product_authorized_xxx' )
```

where xxx is the if of the membership.

But I'm trying to figure out how much time have $user_id been under that membership, and if its a monthly subscription how many months have he renewed.

Is there anyway to achieve this with memberpress functions or classes instead of a rusty database query?

Answer (score 0):

```
$membership_id = membership plan id.

$expiring_txn = MeprUser::get_user_product_expires_at_date($current_user->ID, $membership_id, true); 

if(!empty($expiring_txn)){

echo $created_at = MeprAppHelper::format_date($expiring_txn->created_at, _x('Never', 'ui', 'memberpress'));

echo $expires_at = MeprAppHelper::format_date($expiring_txn->expires_at, _x('Never', 'ui', 'memberpress'));

}
```